# Is this a Sobolev space?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$ be a measure space with $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^n$. Furthermore, let $\mathcal C^p(\Omega,\mathbb R)$ the space of all $p$-times continuously differentiable functions $\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$. Is the space $$\left\{f\in\mathcal C^p(\Omega,\mathbb R) : \int_\Omega \big\vert\mathrm D^\alpha f(\omega)\big\vert\,\mathrm d\mu<\infty~~\text{for all $\alpha\in(\mathbb N_0)^p$ with $\vert\alpha\vert\leq p$} \right\}$$
a Sobolev space $\mathcal W^{\ell, m}$ for a particular choice of $m,\ell$? That is, the space of all continuously differentiable functions with integrable partial derivatives. Here $\mathrm D^\alpha$ denotes the (strong) derivative operator $\frac{\partial^{\vert\alpha\vert}}{\partial^{\alpha_1}\partial^{\alpha_2}\cdots\partial^{\alpha_p}}$.

Comment: Should it really be $D^\alpha|f(\omega)|$?

Comment: Ive tried writing an answer, but I need some information: Which topologies do you use? Do you use the uniform topology on $C^p(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$? What makes a Sobolev space a Sobolev space for you? Also, as MaoWao mentioned, the absolute value is rather untypical.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typo, I have fixed it. I use the uniform topology on $\mathcal C^p$. Regarding the last question, from what I know, Sobolev spaces are defined in terms of weak derivatives. This is why I was wondering whether the above set could be understood as a Sobolev space since in case strong and weak derivative exist, they coincide

Comment: Are you asking if it is the same as the space of functions with certain weak derivatives? This question has answer no, because having $p$ weak derivatives does not imply having $p$ strong derivatives

Comment: Ok, first of all, $\Omega$ must be an open set inside $\mathbb R^n$. Otherwise it is unclear what a "derivative" is. Apart from that, your space is not complete. Completing it will yield the $W$ space you mention. There is a famous paper on this, whose title is "H = W" (but I forgot the authors! :-( ). In any case, it is in the chapter on Sobolev spaces in the PDE book by Craig Evans.

Comment: @CalvinKhor yes, that was basically the question. But does having $p+r$ weak derivatives (for some $r>0$) imply having $p$ strong derivatives?

Comment: @lmaosome yes, having strictly more than $p+n$ weak derivatives that are also integrable implies you have $p$th order weak derivatives, and the highest order ones are Holder continuous. This is a consequence of Morrey’s inequality

Comment: perfect, thank you.